# Why doesn't ALL function ignore filter when data is sliced by columns in pivot table?

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I'm new to the DAX world and I just faced a conceptual misunderstanding.

While I was trying to debug a measure, I found a unexpected (for me) behaviour with the ALL function. I wrote a simple measure COUNTROWS(ALL(Table)) but to my surprise, when I sliced the data by a column, the same number did not appear in each cell in the values field, ignoring the filter context in the way I was expecting:

[image: An image to help ilustrate what I mean.]

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no BUYs on e.g. 01/08/2017, it's not even evaluating the measure. Since that cell doesn't correspond to any rows in the original table, it's not doing any computations.

If you had a BUY and a SELL on the same day, it should show up in both columns on that day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My misunderstanding was to assume that the measure would always be calculated, regardless of existing or not a row in the original table.I will take note of this behaviour!